# Incoming Email in sharepoint2013 not showing in drop folder

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, incoming-email

I configured Incoming Emails in sharepoint 2013 few months ago and it worked perfectly.

but suddenly it stopped working and I've been looking for the reason but couldn't get it yet.

the Emails are not showing in the Drop folder at all. but when I tried to manually put email inside Drop folder it stays there 
and if I put email in Pickup Folder the Document library received it perfectly.

Why emails are not showing in drop folder. what could be the issue?

Thanx

Comment: Is the SMTP Service still running? does the smtp service allows mails from your mailserver?